# Calling str_contains or any PHP function in XSLT to match a string to a pattern

Tags: php, function, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to use a PHP function to see if a comment in a XSLT contains "Written by."

I have not had any luck with str_contains:

```
<!-- in a loop -->
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="php:functionString('str_contains', 'Written by', comment)">
       <xsl:value-of select="comment"/>
  </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

My understanding is the function goes: (PHP Function, Pattern to Match, Variable) but it is not working (the condition is not true when the data is matched).

I am wondering:

1. Is it a version problem? str_contains must be PHP 8 but maybe the server is 7. Not sure.
2. Is it a syntax problem?
3. If it is a version problem, what is a different function to see if a comments begins with or contains that pattern to match?

Comment: "not working" is not a good description of a problem. If you are using XSLT, why don't you use native XSLT (or rather XPath) functions like `starts-with()` or `contains()`?

Comment: The contains() works. Please post a reply and I will accept that. Thanks. 

This is what I used:
<xsl:if test="contains(comment, 'Written by')"><xsl:value-of select="comment"/></xsl:if>

Comment: I believe you could shorten that to `<xsl:value-of select="comment[contains(., 'Written by')]"/>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the condition is not true when the data is matched

If the function is returning a wrong result then you're probably not using it correctly. If it were a version problem (i.e. function not supported), I would expect an error message.

> what is a different function to see if a comments begins with or contains that pattern

XPath has native functions for both - and IMHO they should be your first choice when using XSLT, before you reach for extension functions:

- [starts-with()](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-starts-with)
- [contains()](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-contains)